# Getting Javascript TypeError when trying to access method on my model

Tags: javascript, model

I created a simple model and am trying to test out the setter method on it. When using it in the Chrome javascript console I get a TypeError with a type of "undefined_method".

Here's a link to the code
http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/Rq4Tj/

I am calling it like so:

```
Model.Movie.setTitle('Resident Evil');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `change` on the string `'Resident Evil'`:

```
setTitle : function(title){

    this.title = title;

    this.title.change(function(){ // <-- here
       console.log('title has changed to: ' + title); 
    });

},
```

There is no such method defined on strings. If you're trying to *fire* a `change` event to notify listeners that the `title` changed, you'll have to approach this from a different angle.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I appreciate it. Can you point me in the right direction for how to accomplish this please? :-)

Comment: [Searching is easy](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+fire+custom+event) but [I'll do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028456/how-to-fire-personal-event-in-javascript) [it for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015680/custom-event-library-for-javascript-are-there-any-recommendations) [you anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524697/javascript-event-simulation-library)

Comment: thanks Matt. Based on some of those links, here's what I have which is still throwing the same error

        setTitle : function(title){

            this.title = title;
            //console.log(this.title);

            this.title.bind('titleChangedEvent', function(){
                console.log('your title changed')
            });

            this.title.trigger('titleChangedEvent');
        },

Comment: Dude, `title` is still a string. It doesn't have `bind` or `trigger` functions. **It's just a string.**

Comment: Dude, this is exactly why I am asking for assistance. Instead of sarcastically stating how easy searching is (by the way none of those helped) just provide a simple code example. If you are not able, then please don't waste my time with your comments.

Comment: In order to use DOM events, you need to fire them from a DOM element (which a string is obviously not). If you don't mind using a library, I would recommend using Backbone.js to add the ability to bind/fire events generically: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with setTitle() method, if I comment out the three lines commented below it works.

```
    setTitle : function(title){

        this.title = title;
        console.log(title);

        //this.title.change(function(){
        //   console.log('title has changed to: ' + title);
        //});

    },
```